# Specify folder in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I found a sample batch file I am trying to use to delete files after they are 5 days old.  I've been testing it using the "echo" command and it works.  The only problem I am having is that I want it to delete every file inside of the folder but not the folder.

```
forfiles -p "E:\Programs\SickBeard\SickBeard\lib" -s -m *.* -d -5 -c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

I've tried changing the path to "...\lib\"  and I've tried changing @file to @path but none of these seem to work.

How can I specify all files inside the folder to be deleted but not the folder itself?  I am going to be using task scheduler to run this file once a day.  Thank you in advance.

EDIT:  Oh and for the record, that is just a test folder.  Also, will this work on Windows 8.1?  I am currently using Windows 7 and it seems to be working fine, but I will be using this on a new Windows 8.1 build.

Comment: does `...\lib\*` work? Have a look at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) and see if anything there can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `forfiles` command deals only with the files and not with folders. So your command is absolutely fine (should be on Win8 too..).

If you want to use the forfiles command for deleting the folders, below is one such example.

```
forfiles -p "C:\Sample" -d -5 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

Cheers, G

Comment: When I try to use the code I specified above:


`forfiles -p "E:\Programs\SickBeard\SickBeard\lib" -s -m *.* -d -5 -c "cmd /c echo @file"`


I just get this error:  "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."

Comment: EDIT:  Will this delete anything that hasn't been _CREATED_ or _MODIFIED_ in the last 5 days?  I may have found the problem if it is set to delete any file that hasn't modified in the last 5 days.

Comment: As per the documentation `Selects files with a last modified date within the specified time frame` yes, this will list out the files modified (and obviously created) n days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Delete those files you want and avoid the pesky *No files found* "error" and the corresponding errorlevel of 1--while retaining other more valuable errors from the FORFILES command:

```
cmd /e:on /c "forfiles /p "<insert your directory here>" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c del @path" 2>&1 |  findstr /V /O /C:"ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria."2>&1 | findstr ERROR&&EXIT 1||EXIT 0"&EXIT %errorlevel%
```